# Using a custom value resolver with one argument in the MapFrom() method results in an error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper for creating a mapping between a `Sourcingbundle` object and `ResponsibleDto`. The code for `ResponsibleDto` looks like this:

```cs
public class ResponsibleDto
{  
    public string? BtvPurchasedPartPlanner { get; set; }

    public string? BrManager { get; set; }

    public string? MgMstSpokesperson { get; set; }
    
    private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<Sourcingbundle, ResponsibleDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.BtvPurchasedPartPlanner, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(new BtvPurchasedPartPlannerResolver()))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.BrManager, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(new BrManagerResolver()))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.MgMstSpokesperson, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(new MgMstSpokespersonResolver()));
        }
    }
```

The code for the three resolvers:

```
private class BtvPurchasedPartPlannerResolver : IValueResolver<Sourcingbundle, ResponsibleDto, string?>
    {
        public string? Resolve(Sourcingbundle source, ResponsibleDto destination,
            string? destMember,
            ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var responsible = source.Responsibles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ResponsibleType == ResponsibleType.MM_PLAN);
            
            if (responsible is null) return "";

            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Firstname) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Surname))
                ? string.Join(responsible.Firstname, responsible.Surname)
                : "";
        }
    }

    private class BrManagerResolver : IValueResolver<Sourcingbundle, ResponsibleDto, string?>
    {
        public string? Resolve(Sourcingbundle source, ResponsibleDto destination,
            string? destMember,
            ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var responsible = source.Responsibles.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ResponsibleType == ResponsibleType.MM_MANAGE);
            
            if (responsible is null) return "";

            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Firstname) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Surname))
                ? string.Join(responsible.Firstname, responsible.Surname)
                : "";
        }
    }
    
    private class MgMstSpokespersonResolver : IValueResolver<Sourcingbundle, ResponsibleDto, string?>
    {
        public string? Resolve(Sourcingbundle source, ResponsibleDto destination,
            string? destMember,
            ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var responsible = source.Responsibles.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ResponsibleType == ResponsibleType.MM_SPOKESMAN);
            
            if (responsible is null) return "";

            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Firstname) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Surname))
                ? string.Join(responsible.Firstname, responsible.Surname)
                : "";
        }
    }
```

Because the three resolvers look almost equal, I want to create one Resolver for all three cases which would accept an argument that defines the ResponsibleType. So I would have the following mapping:

```
private class Mapping : Profile
    {
        public Mapping()
        {
            CreateMap<Sourcingbundle, ResponsibleDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.BtvPurchasedPartPlanner, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(new ResponsiblePersonResolver(ResponsibleType.MM_PLAN)))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.BrManager, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(new ResponsiblePersonResolver(ResponsibleType.MM_MANAGE)))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.MgMstSpokesperson, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(new ResponsiblePersonResolver(ResponsibleType.MM_SPOKESMAN)));
        }
    }
```

But the problem is that I am getting the following error:

> ```
> Application terminated unexpectedly
> System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor
> ```
>
> 'ServiceType:
> Application.SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePersonRe
> solver Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Application.SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePersonResolver':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'Domain.Entities.ResponsibleType'
> while at
> tempting to activate 'Application.SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePersonResolver'.)
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType:
> Application.SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePersonResolver
> Lifetime: Transient Implem
> entationType: Application.SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePersonResolver':
> Unable to resolve service for type 'Domain.Entities.ResponsibleType'
> while attempting to activate 'Application
> .SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePersonResolver'.
> ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Domain.Entities.ResponsibleType' while attempting to
> activate
> 'Application.SourcingControl.Queries.GetSourcingBundleDetails.ResponsibleDto+ResponsiblePe
> rsonResolver'.

The new Resolver that I created looks like this:

```
private class ResponsiblePersonResolver : IValueResolver<Sourcingbundle, ResponsibleDto, string?>
    {
        private ResponsibleType _ResponsibleType { get; }
    
        public ResponsiblePersonResolver(ResponsibleType responsibleType)
        {
            _ResponsibleType = responsibleType;
        }   

        public string? Resolve(Sourcingbundle source, ResponsibleDto destination,
            string? destMember,
            ResolutionContext context)
        {
            var responsible = source.Responsibles.FirstOrDefault(r => r.ResponsibleType == _ResponsibleType);
            
            if (responsible is null) return "";
    
            return (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Firstname) &&
                    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(responsible.Surname))
                ? string.Join(responsible.Firstname, responsible.Surname)
                : "";
        }
    }
```

The code for ResponsibleType type used in defining `ResponsibleType` property is:

```
public enum ResponsibleType
{
    MM_PURCHASING,
    MM_PARTS,
    MM_PLAN,
    MM_BRPURCHASING,
    MM_TEAM,
    MM_MANAGE,
    MM_SPOKESMAN,
    MM_PURCHASE_EX,
    MM_TOOL,
    UNKNOWN
}
```

And the r in source.Responsibles is of type Responsible which is just a class(entity) that represents a table in the database. I expanded the Responsible entity with a partial class:

```
public partial class Responsible
{
    public ResponsibleType ResponsibleType
    {
        get
        {
            Enum.TryParse(Responsibleid, true, out ResponsibleType type);
            return type;
        }
    }
}
```

where `Responsibleid` is a column that actually contains the values defined in the enum `ResponsibleType`.

So, the problem is that it is unable to resolve `ResponsibleType`. I don't know how to solve the problem. I tried to do something in the service configuration, but I did not succeed. The code for the service configuration is:

```
public static class ConfigureServices
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
    {
        serviceCollection.AddAutoMapper(
            cfg =>
            {
                cfg.DestinationMemberNamingConvention = new LowerUnderscoreNamingConvention();
            },
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        serviceCollection.AddMediatR(config =>
        {
            config.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            config.AddBehavior(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(UnhandledExceptionBehaviour<,>));
        });
        return serviceCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a default constructor to the resolver. It seems simpler than trying to exclude it somehow from assembly scanning.